# Create IE only css and also individual IE version?

Tags: internet-explorer, target, versions

I've created few IE conditional comments where:

IE 8 and below will use *.ie8AndBelow*

IE 9 will use *.ie9*

IE 10 and above *will not add any class*

*Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]><html class="ie8AndBelow"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>
....
....
```

However there is one problem, how do I write a condition that only target the IE browsers (regardless of any version), I would like to add a css call *.ieOnly* to internet explorer only. The only solution I've got is to link it to another css file but not create an individual class to the html tag itself

```
 <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend this as it's deprecated in newer versions of IE, but if you want to use it, support was only added in IE5 so you could use:

```
<!--[if gte IE 5 ]><html class="ieOnly"><![endif]-->
```

This would apply to IE5+ (surely nobody is still using older versions), although support has been dropped so a JavaScript solution might be better. Here's one possible solution:
[Internet Explorer (IE) version detection in JavaScript](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/)